# Eclipse - Problems saving workspace when projects depend on JPA project

Tags: java, eclipse

I get "Problems saving workspace" window every time i close Eclipse 2020-12, when i have projects that depends on another jpa project in workspace.

[image: Error picture]

Whole error line:

`class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.IUpdatableModule$AddReads (org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ModuleUpdater$$Lambda$967/0x0000000801b34c38 and org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.IUpdatableModule$AddReads are in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @7034465e)`

**See that** error is same for every project in workspace that depends on that one jpa project. I use module-info and Maven.

Do not know what information should i provide, so i am atleast attaching log file from .metadata folder:
https://justpaste.it/9ltow.
Have not noticed any other serious problem about that error. It is just annoying.

Comment: Possibly Eclipse bug [569512](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569512), marked as fixed in 4.19 (2021-03)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse bug marked as fixed in 4.19 (2021-03). Tested it with developer release Version: 2021-03 RC1 (4.19.0 RC1).